# Shaco and Heimer... What was I doing wrong?

Tags: league-of-legends

Today while playing as Heimer with a Shaco on ARAM, he kept repeatedly abusing me, right from the start of the game (hadn't even started battling). I figured he didn't like me using my turrets near his boxes, and after the first time, I stopped using my turrets anywhere near his boxes. But he didn't want me to use them anywhere else either, because the abuse didn't stop.

After that, I was basically useless because I could only use `w`, `e`, or auto attack, and Heimer relies on his turrets.  I don't even know what was going wrong.  Since I was 3/1/16, it could not have been that I was feeding.

There was no explanation for his anger, but *I would like to know if there is some reason why Shaco would have problems with Heimer's turrets*. Any guesses, anyone?

I thought putting the first turret in the brush next to his box was actually a good thing.  With a box and a turret together, they would go for my turret and get feared by the box.  Did I maybe reveal his box? I would think a hidden box would stay hidden whether there is a turret there or not.

Comment: This is a question you shouldn't be asking. Think of this site as a community wiki about games in general (included LoL), but with questions and answers (not related to player behaviour at all though).

Comment: As for the toxic person, you should report him in the after game screen. :P

Comment: @Fabián There is a valid question here, "Why would Shaco dislike me putting turrets on the map/near his boxes?"  It just appears that the answer is "The Shaco you were playing with was a toxic player."

Comment: yes, Namfuak is right, its not about his behavior, its why...what was I doing wrong...

Comment: @cloudymusic, Strixvaria... have you read my question? I was asking for an explanation based on facts. What was I doing wrong? Its not based on opinions. And I asked the question here as only an experienced league player would be able to tell me what was wrong.

Comment: @andrew It's difficult to know based solely on your description. If you had a replay or something we could look at, we might be able to tell you, but as-is we can only speculate. It sounds like he was just being a jerk though.

Comment: Thank you Batophobia. Yes it reads so much better now :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think its a matter of range. The heimerdinger turrent has an higher range(450) then his boxes(425) so ppl get scared by the turrent before they set off the boxes.

Other then that the shaco player is just a "unfriendly" player and should be ignored altogether

Comment: The second paragraph is the more important one here.  He may have had a legitimate reason to dislike your turret placements, but if he's just acting like a kid throwing a tantrum it's not worth trying to figure out why.

Comment: Yeah and with any kid throwing a tantrum, ignore it and move on. Just play your game and don't let the trolls and flamers get to you

Comment: Thanks guys. I really am trying to figure out what I did wrong, because I only started playing League 3 months ago, and the shaco player is gold 3. so I figure   theres something I was doing wrong ....

Comment: Myabe it is the range:/, but I've seen people usually try to take out the turrets and the box and the turret together would be more effective...

Comment: I mean I thought they would be more effective together...becos melees would come within range to hit the turret and be feared..

Comment: Guessing you arent lvl 30 yet and you play in EUW flamers etc is something you should get used to. EUW is one of the most toxic area's + Low level play is usually filled with smurfs which flame all the more instead of teaching the newer players